# Loop and compare values from array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

In Sheet1 I have a single column with populated cells from 1-20 row with regular numbers. Look at picture bellow:

[image]

In Sheet2 I have also a single column, cells are starting from 5-25. If I enter some values into these cells, in Sheet1 from cell with that same value to column "D" background color is changed. Look at pictures bellow to see how it works:

[image][image]

I'm doing it with this piece of code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row >= 5 Then
    If Target.Offset(0, 0).Text <> "" Then
    Dim n As Long
        For n = 5 To 25
            If Target.Offset(0, 0).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & n).Value Then
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & n & ":D" & n).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        Next n
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Now, I'd like to make some kind of check every time Sheet1 is activated, in a way if there are no values in cells `Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone` for all the cells in Range("A1:A20"), if there is a value in some cells `Interior.ColorIndex = 3` for those cells. I was thinking about to put these values into an array and then loop through it to compare values but I'm new to VBA so help would be welcome. If there is a better solution, just bring it on.

Also, I'd like to make a piece of code for a situation if I replace value 12 with 17 that `Interior.ColorIndex` of cell that contains 12 goes to `xlNone` and of 17 `Interior.ColorIndex` goes to "`3`".

So, every suggestion is welcome.

Comment: @pnuts Actually, I didn't know anything about conditional formatting till now. Now I know so ... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No VBA is needed, as [pnuts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505120/pnuts) says.

The easiest way to do this with the colours is with **Conditonal Formatting** using *Formula* to check the value of the cells in column A on one sheet against the values in the rows where you want the colour to change and apply the formatting.

See:

- [MSDN Office Online: Use a formula to apply conditional formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-HA102809768.aspx)
- [Contextures.com: Excel Conditional Formatting -- Examples](http://www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat03.html)
- [Chip Pearson Excel MVP: Conditional Formatting](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/cformatting.htm)
- [J-Walk Mr Spreadsheet: Conditional Formatting](http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/usertips/tip006.htm)

**BUT** if you want VBA, then you can do this in the workbook and worksheet event handlers.

**Worksheet Selection/Activation:**

in Excel on Sheet1, right-click on the sheetname at the bottom, and click *View Code*. This will open the class module for Sheet1 in the VB Editor.

At the top of the code module on the left, select **Worksheet** from the drop-down, and on the right drop-down, click the *Activate* event-handler.

This will create an empty sub-routine that will be executed by Excel everytime that you select the Sheet1 worksheet.

In that code you can make your checks.

**Cell changes on sheet2:**

To get code to run everytime you make a cell change on sheet2, you need to open the class module for sheet2, select **Worksheet** from the drop-down on the left, and *Change* for the event.

This code will run everytime you change a cell on sheet2 and in here, you would write code that first checks if the **Target** argument is in your range like this:

```
If not Application.Intersect(Target, "A5:25") Then Exit Sub
```

Next you want to write your code to check if the value is no longer matching, and reset the colours.

HTH

Philip

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I've took your suggestion on using conditional formatting, figured out the formula that fits me the best and it worked as I wanted it. Thank you for sharing your knowledge with me!